# kafka zookeeper digest authetication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to configure Digest authentication between kafka and zookeeper. I followed [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication) doc for enabling it. I set zookeeper.set.acl=true. In kafka
If I try to configure jaas file(with digest config) and set zookeeper.sasl.client=false, kafka throws error from JaasUtils.class
If I set zookeeper.sasl.client=true, Digest acl is not set for the zookeeper nodes created

Please help!